# Spring Batch - Sybase Attempted conversion between an illegal pair of types

Tags: spring-batch

I'm getting below exception while running a job in SpringBatch using sybase db. The schema have been created using - 'schema-sybase.sql' shipped with Spring Batch.

**Spring-batch** version - spring-batch-core-2.1.7

**Error**

> 2015-04-07 09:21:13,138 ERROR
>   [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner] -
>   
>   org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from
>   BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; JZ006: Caught
>   IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0TC: Attempted conversion between
>   an illegal pair of types.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   JZ006: Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0TC: Attempted
>   conversion between an illegal pair of types.

**Job Configuration**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="../launch-context.xml"/>
                         
     <beans:bean id="helloWorld" class="com.chatar.batch.practice.HelloWorld"
      scope="step">
     <beans:property name="name" value="#{jobParameters[name]}"/>
 </beans:bean>

    <step id="helloWorldStep">
        <tasklet ref="helloWorld"/>
    </step>

    <job id="helloWorldJob" incrementer="idIncrementer">
        <step id="helloWorldStep1" parent="helloWorldStep"/>
         <listeners>
         <listener ref="loggingListener"/>
     </listeners>
    </job>
    
    <beans:bean id="loggingListener" class="com.chatar.batch.practice.listener.JobLoggerListener"/>
    
    <beans:bean id="idIncrementer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: What version of sybase and what version of the driver?

Comment: driver - jconn-3.0.0, sybase - Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 21708 SMP SP110 /P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/ase157sp11x/3546/64-bit/FBO/Fri Nov  8 05:39:38 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it worked fine after changing BIGINT to INTEGER in schema-sybase.sql.

Look like some issue with sybase and JDBC driver compatibility.

The above solution is tested with jconn-3.0.0.jar

Comment: For the record, both your driver and the version of Spring Batch you're using are *very* old.  You may want to consider upgrading...

Comment: Thanks, upgrading Sybase is out of my control (as it's decided by different team and applicable to all environments) but I would definitely try upgrading driver...

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine with BIGINT after upgrading JDBC driver to version 7.0.7 - 
**jconn-7.0.7.jar**